# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validate{ouuowwd

Tags: php, laravel

Please, what is the meaning of this error and how do i solve it. I tried to submit form and i get this error.

i have searched for other similar problems but i didnt get this type of error

Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validate{ouuowwd

i dont know how to go about it

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PropertyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }
    
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.uploadapartment', [
            'states' => State::all(),
            'areas' => Area::all(),
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'building' => 'required',
            'buildingtype' => 'required',
            'flatbuildingtype' => 'nullable',
            'buildingincompound' => 'required',
            'firstfloor' => 'nullable',
            'secondfloor'=> 'nullable',
            'thirdfloor' => 'nullable',
            'bedroom1' => 'image'|'nullable',
            'kitchenpic' => 'image'|'nullable',
            'bedroom2' => 'image'|'nullable',
            'bedroom3' => 'image'|'nullable',
            'bedroom4' => 'image'|'nullable',
            'address' => 'string'|'required',
            'area' => 'string'|'required',
            'state'=> 'string'|'required',
            'meetingplace'=> 'string'|'required'
        ]);

        $apartment = Property::create([
            'building' => $request-> building,
            'FlatType' => $request->flatbuildingtype,
            'firstfloor' => $request->firstfloor,
            'secondfloor'=> $request->secondfloor,
            'room3' => $request->bedroom3,
            'kitchenpic' => $request->kitchenpic,
            'compound' => $request->bedroom4,
        ]);

        $apartment->save();

        return redirect('/')->with('status', 'Your apartment for rent was successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you're reading the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic. This shows the correct usage, as either `'image|nullable'` (a single `string`, with each Rule separated by `|`), or `['image', 'nullable']` (each Rule in an `array` as a `string`). What you have here is neither of those. 

Comment: Technically they are still strings. The value they hold is wrong though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for the validation rules is wrong.

```
'bedroom1' => 'image'|'nullable',
'kitchenpic' => 'image'|'nullable',
'bedroom2' => 'image'|'nullable',
'bedroom3' => 'image'|'nullable',
'bedroom4' => 'image'|'nullable',
'address' => 'string'|'required',
'area' => 'string'|'required',
'state'=> 'string'|'required',
'meetingplace'=> 'string'|'required'
```

should be

```
'bedroom1' => 'image|nullable',
'kitchenpic' => 'image|nullable',
'bedroom2' => 'image|nullable',
'bedroom3' => 'image|nullable',
'bedroom4' => 'image|nullable',
'address' => 'string|required',
'area' => 'string|required',
'state'=> 'string|required',
'meetingplace'=> 'string|required'
```

or

```
'bedroom1' => ['image', 'nullable'],
'kitchenpic' => ['image', 'nullable'],
'bedroom2' => ['image', 'nullable'],
'bedroom3' => ['image', 'nullable'],
'bedroom4' => ['image', 'nullable'],
'address' => ['string', 'required'],
'area' => ['string', 'required'],
'state'=> ['string', 'required'],
'meetingplace'=> ['string', 'required'],
```

---

The weird error you're getting probably originates from this. You're using the bitwise OR operator on two strings. It made all your rules nonsense.

For example

```
'bedroom' => 'image'|'nullable'
```

evaluates to

```
'bedroom' => 'o}moeble'
```